# Replacing labels c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

created a sports table that shows different statistics sorted by one property. When sorting for a different property I created completely new labels that just sit on top of the old ones instead of replacing them.

This is ran when a button is pressed:

```
private void Points_Order(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<Team> leagueTeams = new List<Team>();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TXT1.txt"))
    {
        using (JsonReader jr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
        {
            JsonSerializer js = new JsonSerializer();
            leagueTeams = js.Deserialize<List<Team>>(jr);
        }
    }

    List<Team> sortedList = leagueTeams.OrderByDescending(o => o.points).ToList(); //orders the keagueTeams list by points and stores in a new list using linq
    List<Label> TeamLabels = new List<Label>(); //makes list of labels that show the teams
    List<string> Names = new List<string>(); //Creates a list for the names 

    List<Label> gamesPlayedLabels = new List<Label>();
    List<int> GamesPlayed = new List<int>();

    foreach (var properties in sortedList)
    {
        Names.Add(properties.name);//adds the name of each object into the Names list
        GamesPlayed.Add(properties.gamesPlayed);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        string nameLab = Names[i];
        TeamLabels.Add(new Label { Height = 100, Width = 100, Content = nameLab }); //sets position of the name labels
        Canvas.SetLeft(TeamLabels[i], 0);
        Canvas.SetTop(TeamLabels[i], (i * 19) + 19);
        canvas1.Children.Add(TeamLabels[i]);

        string played = Convert.ToString(GamesPlayed[i]);
        gamesPlayedLabels.Add(new Label { Height = 100, Width = 100, Content = played });
        Canvas.SetLeft(gamesPlayedLabels[i], 112);
        Canvas.SetTop(gamesPlayedLabels[i], (i * 19) + 19);
        canvas1.Children.Add(gamesPlayedLabels[i]);
    }
}
```

When a second button is pressed the exact same code is ran but apart from

```
List<Team> sortedList = leagueTeams.OrderByDescending(o => o.points).ToList()
```

it is

```
List<Team> sortedList = leagueTeams.OrderBy(o => o.name).ToList();
```

so the question is can you replace existing labels so the table can be sorted?

Comment: Apparently the code just keeps adding labels (Canvas Children) but never removes them. `Remove()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF - is there a way to remove specific child from Canvas.Children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280176/wpf-is-there-a-way-to-remove-specific-child-from-canvas-children)

Comment: Ihave two button click methods, if I use that link and use the .children.remove all the labels on screen would be deleted so the buttons would have to also add labels that were intended to never be moved and are there before any button press?

Comment: Code that manipulates the UI like this in the code-behind is already broken. You should be using a view model with a collection that represents the labels, bound to an `ItemsControl` that uses a `Canvas` as the `ItemsPanel`, with the position for each label determined by the `ItemContainerStyle`. Then the problem is simplified to just updating the collection (which should be `ObservableCollection<T>`), and let WPF do all the rest of the work.